# Calculated Field - Summing Measures with Dimension

Tags: google-analytics, calculated-field, tableau-api

[image]

I want to get the Total AUTO MQL for Form Fills. The end result should be in Measure. I don't know the syntax.

Comment: What have you tried? What should the end result look like? It sounds like you want to sum 'From Fills' then add 'AUTO MQL' to the marks card.

Comment: please provide some sample input and the related sample output

Comment: Hi Guys, was able to create a syntax for it.

Comment: Hi Guys, I was able to create a syntax for it.                                                                  IF [Auto-MQLs]= 'Sales' THEN ZN([Form Fills])
ELSEIF  [Auto-MQLs]= 'Request a Tour' THEN ZN([Form Fills])
ELSEIF  [Auto-MQLs]= 'Digital Edge' THEN ZN([Form Fills])
ELSEIF  [Auto-MQLs]= 'GIT' THEN ZN([Form Fills])
ELSE 0
END